# Data Extension CSV upload - breakdown of which records were added, skipped & updated

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, fileupload

I've added data to a Data Extension via CSV upload.

I've had the confirmation email saying:
"X have been inserted, X have been updated"

Is there anywhere that I can see which records were inserted and which were updated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once a Data Extension is updated, you will not be able to get the list of records that were Added or the records that were updated.

You could either extract the data from the Data Extension or create a copy of the Data Extension before performing your Import.